# How to add searchview in custom ToolBar in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am creating a notes app with single activity and 3 fragments. I created a custom Toolbar and want to add searchview inside it(for the HomeNoteFragment) . Also i want to hide this toolbar when moving to other fragments(EditNote and CreateNote Fragments).
I implemented by creating options menu but my app crashes.
here is MainActivity.kt file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var navController : NavController

    private lateinit var viewModel: NotesViewModel
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

     
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[NotesViewModel::class.java]

        
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

}
```

HomeNoteFragment

```
class HomeNoteFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home_note) {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeNoteBinding
    private val viewModel: NotesViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var notesAdapter: NotesAdapter

    private lateinit var navController: NavController



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentHomeNoteBinding.bind(view)


         navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

        val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolBarHomeNoteFragment)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
      

        setUpRecyclerView()

        binding.llFabAddNote.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeNoteFragment_to_createNotesFragment)
        }
        binding.fabAddNote.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeNoteFragment_to_createNotesFragment)
        }

        
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        binding.rvNotesList.layoutManager =
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
       
        notesAdapter = NotesAdapter(requireContext())
        binding.rvNotesList.adapter = notesAdapter


        viewModel.allNotes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { list ->
            if (list.isEmpty()) {

                binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                binding.noData.visibility = View.GONE
                notesAdapter.updateList(list)
               
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view)
        val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "Search Notes..."

        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {

            override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true)

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(nextText: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                if(newText!=null) {
                    notesAdapter.filterList(newText)
                }
                return true
            }

        })
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }


}
```

HomeNoteFragment XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeNoteFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/toolBarHomeNoteFragment"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="Notes">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:queryHint="Search Notes..."
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
                app:queryBackground="@color/white"
               />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvNotesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/items_notes" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/noData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/noDataAnimation"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/notes" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splashAppName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="No Notes Here.."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/noDataAnimation" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <!--    add background in ll-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFabAddNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_btn_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="#4F6265"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabAddNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:backgroundTint="#D5151515"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="30dp"
            app:rippleColor="#3F6468"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            app:useCompatPadding="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddNoteFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Add Note"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am using navigation component for the navigatin between fragments.

i tried to various methods available but failed. Want to add searchview inside my custom toolbar for the homeNotes Fragment where all the notes will be displayed and want to hide this toolbar when moving to other fragments(EditNote and CreateNote Fragments).